# Pycharm install button for packages not available

Tags: python, pycharm, package, installation

I want to install additional packages in pycharm, but the install button in the project interpreter is not active. I think this might be due to the virtual environment I created but not sure. Please see img, can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I switched current python interpreter to another and then switched back, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

`Python 3.6` does not fully update all packages . It is better to use  `Python 3.5`.

To install packages for Python you can use in command interpreter  ....

```
pip install 'your desire package name'
```

> if you don't have pip installed then you can install pip from here ...
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/